# Why does everything I do seem to use all my CPU cores?

Tags: cpu, multi-core

I have an [Intel i5 4300m](http://ark.intel.com/products/76347/Intel-Core-i5-4300M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz). When I open the Windows Resource Monitor, it shows 4 cores.

When I perform operations such as using the browser or running a simple Python script, the % usage of all 4 cores go up. I thought only heavy duty operations such as video editing, compressing, and gaming use multiple cores. Why is using my browser using all 4 cores?

I'm looking for a new laptop and I'm deciding between dual and quad cores.

Edit: I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Your current CPU is a dual core with HT. Your OS usually moves processes among cores for various reason. One of them being to avoid having a single core under heavy load. If you have an issue with this you could set the affinity for individual processes.

Comment: I thought you had to manually program support for multiple cores. Is it a recent development to have the OS automatically make programs use multiple cores?

Comment: The application itself isn't using more than a single core. It's just constantly shifted among the available cores. So while you see activity on each core your main application is only using one core at a time. In addition there are various background processes that are running which might cause "actual load" on the other cores.

Comment: In addition to the other sensible comments & answer already here... what benefit would you expect to receive from having one core working hard & the others proverbially twiddling their thumbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a core causes it to heat up. Migrating a task from core to core periodically helps to even the heat generation. This allows the chip to use a higher clock frequency. This reduces the time spent waiting for the CPU and permits I/O to be responded to more quickly.

If the CPU is significantly overpowered for the task, this probably doesn't make that much of a noticeable difference. But the system still behaves optimally for those cases where it does.